# What's the relationship between the async/await pattern and continuations?

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, async-await, continuations, delimited-continuations

I'm wondering what's the relationship between the `async`/`await` pattern (as known from Scala, F#, C#, etc.) and continuations:

- Is the `async`/`await` pattern a limited subset of full-blown continuations? (If true, how are continuations more expressive?)
- Are continuations just one possible implementation technique for `async`/`await`? (If true, what other implementation approaches exist?)
- Or are `async`/`await` and continuations just orthogonal concepts where the only commonality is that they both enable some abstraction of control flow/data flow?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22852251/1768303

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that the relation between the two is this: `async`-`await` is a technique programming languages use so that you can write code that looks synchronous (e.g. no explicit continuation delegates), but that is actually executed asynchronously. This is achieved by creating an object that represents the current state of execution of the function and registering that as the *continuation* of the awaited operation.

In short, `async`-`await` *uses* continuations.

> Is the `async`/`await` pattern a limited subset of full-blown continuations? (If true, how are continuations more expressive?)

You could say that. Continuations are a more general concept, `async`-`await` just uses them to achieve asynchrony.

For example, in [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) programming, you could implement exception handling by having two continuations for each operation: one for the success case and one for the failure case. This use of continuations has nothing to do with `async`-`await` (you would have to write each continuation explicitly, probably as a lambda).

> Are continuations just one possible implementation technique for `async`/`await`? (If true, what other implementation approaches exist?)

I'd say that the concept of continuation is pretty central to `async`-`await`.

The core idea being `async`-`await` is to stop executing the function for now and resume it at a later time. And for that, you need some kind of object that can be used to do that resuming. Which is exactly what a continuation is.

Comment: Also, ContinueWith enables resuming an async method. This would not be possible with raw threads, for example, because you can't get called back when it exits. You can only wait.

Comment: Although, continuation is not necessarily about asynchronous execution. One other example is `yield` which original purpose has nothing to do with asynchrony.

Comment: @Noseratio Yeah, that's part of what I've been trying to say.

Comment: @svick. Thanks for your answer! Could you comment on how async/await uses continuations? (E. g. is it just hooking into shift/reset underneath or is there more magic happening?)

Comment: @soc I think `async`-`await` has nothing to do with delimited continuations, it just uses normal continuations.