# C# are coroutines asynchronous?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm relatively new to c# (not to programming in general), and I cant seem to find an answer to this question that is just plain and simple.

are coroutines asynchronous? (y/n/both/abort)

Comment: for extra clarity: does the coroutine run on the same thread that the main runloop of a program runs on? or is it on a completely different thread?

Comment: C# does not have the notion of coroutine.  It is a specific Unity terminology, it is just an iterator that uses the C# *yield* keyword.  No, they are not asynchronous, they are state machines.  Every time you call it, synchronously, it does something else.

Comment: i see, thanks for clearing that up. thought this was a standard c# feature, bit hard to tell when learning both c# and unity together.

Comment: If this is about unity3d the tag is wrong...

Comment: My take on [async coroutines with C# 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62687410/1768303) using `IAsyncEnumerable`, `IAsyncEnumerator`, `await foreach` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [Eduasync part 13: first look at coroutines with async](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/06/22/eduasync-part-13-first-look-at-coroutines-with-async.aspx). Coroutines are not asyncronous by standard, but using the `await` and `async` (C# 5.0 and .NET 4.5) keyword you can make them to.

Comment: In the context of Unity, [coroutines seem to refer to iterator methods](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Coroutines.html).