# IAsyncEnumerable, yielding from event handler

Tags: c#, async-await, iasyncenumerable

I'm trying to wrap an asynchronous subscription API based on events with an API based on `IAsyncEnumerable`. Basically along the lines of:

```cs
async IAsyncEnumerable<string> ReadAll() 
{
    var reader = new EventBasedReader();
    reader.OnRead => (_, args) => yield return e.Message;
    reader.Start();
    await reader.WaitUntilAllRead();
}
```

However this doesn't work because it's the event handler that yields, and this isn't allowed. Is there another way I can write this to make it work as an `IAsyncEnumerable`?

Comment: You may find this interesting: [Factory for IAsyncEnumerable or IAsyncEnumerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61540896/factory-for-iasyncenumerable-or-iasyncenumerator). Also you could consider adding the [iasyncenumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iasyncenumerable) tag to the question.

Comment: I faced a similar problem and have just [blogged about it](https://dev.to/noseratio/c-events-as-asynchronous-streams-with-reactivex-or-channels-82k).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Wrap an asynchronous subscription API based on events with an API based on `IAsyncEnumerable`.

Those two are not directly compatible. Events are push-based, and enumerables (including async enumerables) are pull-based.

In order to cross that divide, you need a buffer - some place to hold the event data as it is pushed to you but before the downstream code has pulled it.

I recommend using Channels for buffers. If your use case allows it, you could use an unbounded channel:

```
IAsyncEnumerable<string> ReadAll() 
{
  var reader = new EventBasedReader();
  var buffer = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();
  reader.OnRead = async (_, args) => await buffer.Writer.WriteAsync(e.Message);
  reader.Start();
  CompleteBufferWhenEventsAreDone();
  return buffer.Reader.ReadAllAsync();

  async void CompleteBufferWhenEventsAreDone()
  {
    await reader.WaitUntilAllRead();
    buffer.Writer.TryComplete();
  }
}
```

Comment: hi,which is better? thanks.
public interface IPriceService<in TConfig, TPrice>
{
    public Task StartAsync(TConfig configuration, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    public event EventHandler<TPrice> PriceUpdated;
}
public interface IPriceService<in TConfig, out TPrice>
{
    public Task StartAsync(TConfig configuration, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    public IAsyncEnumerable<TPrice> GetPricesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

Comment: It's hard to read code in comments; could you ask your own question?